# Running an Eslint rule twice with different options?

Tags: javascript, eslint

An example of where this would be useful is the "max-len" rule. Currently, it's impossible to ignore long strings (without using a hacky regex). It has an option to ignore entire lines with any strings. This would ignore long lines with
an empty string.

A workaround is increasing the allowed length if the line contains a string with these options:

```
'max-len1': [2, {
  code: 100,
  comments: 200,
  tabWidth: 2,
  ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
  ignoreStrings: true,
  ignoreRegExpLiterals: true,
  ignoreUrls: true,
}],
'max-len2': [2, {
  code: 200,
  comments: 200,
  tabWidth: 2,
  ignoreRegExpLiterals: true,
  ignoreUrls: true,
}]
```

Is it possible to run the rule twice with this 2 options?